# PHP transform string without using regular expression

Tags: php, arrays, string, escaping

Example probably works best.

- `a|b|c` needs to become `array('a', 'b', 'c')`
- `a|\||\}` needs to become `array('a', '\|', '\}')`
- `ab\}aaa|ae\|aa` needs to become `array('ab\}aaa', 'ae\|aa')`

The string that's going to be transformed can have any type of characters, but there are 3 "special" characters that can be interpreted as a straightforward character, only if it is escaped with `\`. `|` separates an option but, if escaped, needs to be interpreted as an option or a part of it (like any other character). `{ and }` are always going to be escaped at this point.

The catch is that I need to do this without using regular expressions.

I have been struggling with this one for 10 hours, and I sure hope anyone has a simple answer to this.

***Edit

My plan was to search for a `|` and if found, check if it is escaped. If yes, then continue searching for the next one. When I find `|`, I would take out the first option of the string, and continue the same way, until there were no `|` left.

```
while ($positionFound != 1) {
            $intPrevPosition = $intPosition;
            $intPosition = strpos($strTemp, '|', $intPosition);
            if ($intPosition === false || (substr_count($strTemp, '|') == 1 && $strTemp{$intPosition + $intPrevPosition - 1} == '\\')) {
                $arrOptions[] = $strTemp;
                $positionFound = 1;
            }
            elseif ($strTemp{$intPosition + $intPrevPosition - 1} != '\\') {
                $intPosition = $intPrevPosition + $intPosition;
                $arrOptions[] = substr(substr($strTemp, 0, $intPosition + 1), 0, -1);
                $strTemp = substr($strTemp, $intPosition + 1);
                $intPosition = 0;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why can't you use a regex?  [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) is the correct tool here.

Comment: If that's some form of homework question without practical use, and you have been attempting solutions *for 10 hours* - then at least share one of them, or your thoughts on how to approach it.

Comment: This is a part of an assignment, and it forbids using regex. I've gotten to the last part of it, but now I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a simple parser:

```
$input = "ab\\}aaa|ae\\|aa"; // ab\}aaa|ae\|aa

$token = "";
$last_char = "";
$len = strlen($input);
$tokens = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i += 1) {
    $char = $input[$i];
    if ($char === "|" && $last_char !== "\\") {
        $tokens[] = $token;
        $token = "";
    }
    $token .= $char;
    $last_char = $char;
}
$tokens[] = $token; // capture last token
var_dump($tokens);
// array('ab\}aaa', 'ae\|aa')
```

Note that with this implementation the escape also triggers on: `ab\\|cd`, the output is `array("ab\\|cd")` and not `array("ab\\", "cd")`.

---

**Nested parser**

For easy of understanding I'm going to forget about the `\` rules for now.

Assume you have: `a{b|c}|{d|e}` and the expected output is: `abd, abe, acd, ace`

First what you gotta do is translate `a{b|c}|{d|e}` into:

```
array(
    "a",
    array("b", "c")
    array("d", "e")
)
```

If the input is `ab{cd|ef}|{gh|ij}` we want:

```
array(
    "ab",
    array("cd", "ef")
    array("gh", "ij")
)
```

And ofcourse multiple levels of nesting should also work: `a{b|{c|d}}|e`

```
array(
    "a",
    array("b", array("c", "d"))
    "e"
)
```

Here is the parse function. I hadn't quite figure out how to combine it back together yet

```
function parse($string, $i = 0) {
    $token = "";
    $tokens = array();
    for (; $i < strlen($string); $i += 1) {
        $char = $string[$i];
        if ($char === "{") {
            if ($token !== "") {
                $tokens[] = $token;
            }
            $token = "";
            $parse = parse($string, $i + 1);
            $tokens[] = $parse["token"];
            $i = $parse["index"];
            continue;
        }
        if ($char === "}") {
            // end of this part
            if ($token !== "") {
                $tokens[] = $token;
            }
            return array(
                "token" => $tokens,
                "index" => $i
            );
        }
        if ($char === "|") {
            if ($token !== "") {
                $tokens[] = $token;
            }
            $token = "";
            continue;
        }
        $token .= $char;
    }
    return $tokens;
}
var_dump(parse("ab{cd|ef}|{gh|ij}"));
```

Comment: I see. Let me think of something.

Comment: Forgive me, Halcyon, nesting was a problem from a different part of this project. This parser is working great. Thank you for your huge help!

Comment: I see, I was working on the nested parser thing. I posted what I had.